# stuck on establishing a tor circuit for the last 40 minutes

Tags: help

[image]
logs are in the SS. i am trying to run it on kali linux

Comment: Your date and time were probably wrong.

Comment: go to your pc setting than time date seting there you found time zone by internet time zone , update that ..and ok your problem is sloved ...bro

Answer (score 1):

One of the most common issues that causes connection errors in Tor Browser is an incorrect system clock. Please make sure your system clock and timezone are set accurately. If this doesn't fix the problem, see the ​Troubleshooting page on the ​Tor Browser User Manual ​https://tb-manual.torproject.org/en-US/troubleshooting.html